# Update a war on Tomcat start up

Tags: tomcat, deployment

I want to setup an update process for an application running on Tomcat. The server which hosts tomcat is only open during working hours (it is an intraner application for a small company). I was thinking that I could upload the new war to the server and set up "something" to run on the next server boot. This something could be a bat file that will be executed on server start up but before the start up of the Tomcat service and it will delete the old war and its exploded folder. When I update manually the war I also delete the work folder of Tomcat (just to be sure). I know about hot deployment but I do not consider it an option since I am not very sure for the implications it might have on the users current working sessions.

Is there a way to run such a bat file before Tomcat start up or an alternative way to do this update? Tomcat version isn't an issue. Now is running Tomcat 6 but I can upgrade to version 7 if needed.

I have also posted this on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/378807/update-a-war-on-tomcat-start-up) but I am posting here and if you think this is in violation of the terms, my apologies and I will remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a batch file that will perform your update then start Tomcat.

Using srvany.exe or FireDaemon make your script a Windows service that will started on machine boot.

Since I prefer Java to bat scripting, I would rather use the [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) to program my Tomcat update and startup and make it a Windows Service.

Comment: I like tha Java approach but how I will make sure that the update service runs before the tomcat service? Do I have to add a dependancy on the tomcat service?

Comment: A small bootsrap Java app that performs your update then starts Tomcat progammatically. Using the Service Wrapper you make this bootsrap app the Windows service. Check this [link](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/integrate-start-stop-nix.html) on how to integrate your app in the wrapper. btw, version 3.2.3 of the wrapper is 'free' if that makes any difference for you.